# Excel lookup function?

Tags: functions

I have two lists, one for the length of words and another list for the corresponding bonus points.

```
play = {"a", "aa", "caa", "ccbaa", "ccxxxcaa", "ccccaa", "cccccaa",   "ccccccaa", "sdf"}  
len = StringLength[play]  
{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 6, 7, 8, 4}  
bonusPoints = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 75, 85, 95, 100}  
(* Excel-like lookup function [len, bonusPoints] *)  
(* 0, 10, 20, 40, 75, 50, 60, 75, 30 *)
```

I have tried with Thread and Lookup but get various errors ("different lengths", etc.). Funny that there is no other question about Excel lookup look alike, it is such a marvellous function. Thank you for your time!

Comment: `bonusPoints[[len]]` ?  ( If your expected result is correct maybe it needs more explination )

Comment: Well, the line `Excel like lookup function` will somehow take len and bonusPoints as parameters. That is what I mean. Or have I misunderstood your comments?

Comment: In addition to what @george2079 said, in more general case that you might encounter non-integers, maybe even `Interpolation[bonusPoints]`? Then, simply `Map[Interpolation[bonusPoints], len]`

Comment: I am sorry, I have corrected the desired output. There are no numbers in between, only integers.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you want the answer to be? As @george2079 said  
`bonusPoints[[len]] ` does return what you want which is {0, 10, 20, 40, 75, 50, 60, 75, 20}. What is wrong with that?
Since you edited you changed the length of the last string so I guess you want the answer's last element to be 20?

Comment: @BehzadNazari, Wow, there is nothing wrong with that, on the contrary, it really solves the problem very well. Thank you very much! I am not sure how to upvote your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building an association is a good tool for tackling this problem because it provides a solution that will be similar to way you would do it in Excel.

```
bonusPoints = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 75, 85, 95, 100};
assoc = AssociationThread[Range[Length[bonusPoints]] -> bonusPoints];
Lookup[assoc, {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 6, 7, 8, 4}]
```

> ```
> {0, 10, 20, 40, 75, 50, 60, 75, 30}
> ```

Comment: The answer with Associations is really pedagogical and solves the problem in an elegant manner. Thank you @m_goldberg.